# t-sql Pivot on all values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with around 10 rows.  I want to pivot on all values in one column to a one-row multi column result.  It looks as though there is no way to get around the "For ContactTypeID in ([1],[2])" syntax.

```
ContactTypeID int
ContactType varchar(20)
```

Sample data:

```
1    Customer
2    Vendor
...
5    BillTo
```

I want to return a single row with

```
Customer  Vendor   BillTo, etc
   1        2         5
```

But like I said, I don't want to have to specify each `ContactTypeID` by number.  Is there way to specify "for all"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a dynamic pivot.

Here's the code, for your reference. Hope it helps.

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (ContactTypeID int, ContactType varchar(20));
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (1, 'Customer'), (2, 'Vendor'), (5, 'BillTo');

DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX);
SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + ContactType + ']', 
               '[' + ContactType + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [ContactType] FROM tablename) PV  
               ORDER BY [ContactType]

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '           
              SELECT * FROM 
             (
                 SELECT * FROM tablename
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(ContactTypeID)
                 FOR [ContactType] IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p      

            '     
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  My mistake, I should have said without dynamic SQL.  Is there a way to do it without it?

Comment: Since you columns depends on the data you have, I don't know a different solution. Although, I'll keep this question in mind and if I have a different approach I'll be back to you. Cheers.